# How to convert character array into a macro identifier in C?

Tags: c, arrays, macros, char

```
#include "uidefs.h"
static int Fn_Press(arguments_t * arglist)
{
    int id = XVAL(arglist->symb_name[0]); //symb_name is a character array of [10][150] dimension
    printf("%d", id);
}
```

I'm passing a string to this function as a parameter of `arglist`. I want to convert the string which is stored in `arglist->symb_name[0]` as a Macro identifier and store the defined value for this macro in variable `id`.

This macro identifier is defined in `uidefs.h` as

```
#define SYMBNAME 2000
```

But the problem with this is when I try to stringify value of `arglist->symb_name[0]`, I don't get the actual value stored in buffer i.e. `SYMBNAME`. Instead, I get `arglist->symb_name[0]`.

Comment: You cannot. Macros are processed even before the compilation is taking place. So such a conversion, even if were possible, is meaningless. And yes, as it is clearly an XY-problem, you should ask about what are you trying to solve by this.

Comment: I want to obtain the #define value for SYMBNAME. My problem is I've > 1000 #defines defined in uidefs.h whose value I want to read depending on the command entered by the user.

Comment: @You *cannot*. If the user is entering a string and you want to find the corresponding value you will have to use some dictionary-like data structure.

Comment: `> 1000 #defines` Write a script to process them into a dictionary-like data structure.

Comment: This cannot be done with macros in C.  You can do it in languages like VBScript and Python.  You need a lookup table with identifier name and identifier address.  Then just look up the name and print the value from the identifier address.

Comment: That is an option, I did not want to take. But seems like that is what I will have to do.